# How to execute spark sql multiline query when stored as a string variable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have code like so with a multiline query

```
  val hiveInsertIntoTable = spark.read.text(fileQuery).collect()
  hiveInsertIntoTable.foreach(println)

  val actualQuery = hiveInsertIntoTable(0).mkString
  println(actualQuery)


  spark.sql(s"truncate table $tableTruncate")
  spark.sql(actualQuery)
```

Whenever I try to execute actual query I get an error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'(line 1, pos 52)
== SQL ==
insert into wera_tacotv_esd.lac_asset_table_pb_hive
```

----------------------------------------------------^^^

```
and the end of the query  .... ;    (terminates in a ;)
```

The query is actually about 450 lines

I tried to wrap  the variable in triple quotes but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using spark 2.1 and scala 2.11

Comment: We'll need to see this query... at least the first 53 characters of it...

Comment: You were right ronhash the error was a combinatrion of the current anser and the fact that I had a ; at the end of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

- `hiveInsertIntoTable` is an `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` - not very useful structure.
- You take only the first row of it `hiveInsertIntoTable(0)`
- Even if you took all rows, concatenating with empty string (`.mkString`) wouldn't work well.

Either:

```
val actualQuery = spark.read.text(path).as[String].collect.mkString("\n")
```

or

```
val actualQuery = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path).values.first()
```